# Changing the entries and columns in an exported CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When exporting the MD5 hashes in a CSV file, it creates three columns: Algorithm, Hash, Path. I want to change that and make it so that only two columns are created: Hash and File Name. Where Path displays the full path (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ExampleFiles\SampleFile.txt for example). However, I want it to only display the name of the file (SampleFile.txt).

If there are files inside more folders then I want it to look like this (TestFolder1\File1.txt) and not (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ExampleFiles\TestFolder1\File1.txt).

The code that I have is this:

```
#Getting the MD5 hash of the source and storing it a csv format
$InstallerPath = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\source\Folder1' -Recurse
$InstallerHash = foreach ($File in $InstallerPath) 
{
    Get-FileHash $File.FullName -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
$InstallerHash | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Exports\SourceHash.csv

#Getting the MD5 hash of the destination and storing it in a csv format
$DestinationPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\destination\Folder1" -Recurse
$DestinationHash = foreach ($File in $DestinationPath) 
{
    Get-FileHash $File.FullName -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
}
$DestinationHash | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Exports\DestinationHash.csv
```

I want the CSV table to look like this:

```
| Hash | FileName |
| ---- | -------- |
| 12345abcde | SampleFile.txt|
| abcde12345 | TestFolder1\File1.txt |
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#Get All files and group by name
$AllFilesGrouped=Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -Recurse | group Name

#take all group, get Nb doublons and loop on file
$AllFilesGrouped |%{

$NbFile=$_.Count

$_.Group | %{

                #If doublon => Filename + Directory
                if ($NbFile -gt 1)
                {
                   $FileName="{0}\{1}" -f $_.Directory.Name , $_.Name
                }
                else
                {
                   $FileName=$_.Name 
                }

                #Build final object
                [pscustomobject]@{

                Hash=(Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Hash
                FileName=$FileName
                }


            }


} | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -notype
```